# Mistakes in pronunciation

Tags: salat, pronunciation

While saying Sami'allah huliman hamida in prayer I said the word hamida with round ha and I didn’t correct it. Is my prayer valid?

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. To learn more about our site and model consider taking our [tour] and checking our [help]. I suppose that you are none Arabic speaker

Comment: As Salaamu 3laykum, please see my answer below regardless of the votes.

Comment: The answer depends on your ability of speaking Arabic. And even then this might not really mean that your prayer could be invalid. But for knowing this we need your feedback! And without this feedback answering this question is meaningless especially if the answer misses the topic of the question as in the case below.